# Entering formula in vba with text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a formula in vba excel but it is returning with error #name
but without text formula is working fine. May be there syntax error. Can anybody help me to solve this
Formula is below

```
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f.&DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4))"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text needs to be surrounded by `""`:

```
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""dd-mm-yyy"")"
```

Comment: ok fine but now it is not returning the date but instead simple number is returning

Comment: I tried to modify formula as "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4),"DD-MMM-YYYY")" but not working

Comment: See edit @Swati again you need to put 2 `"` on each end

Comment: @Swati sorry, I do not know what else I can do, the code above works for me.

Comment: @Swati i had the date as american, try the code above again.

Comment: I modigy formula as Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")" but now 1004 error is there

Comment: @Swati I fixed the date to what you want.  You are missing `)` in yours.

Comment: @Swati please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Does this work only for the English version of Excel or will this also work for non-English versions? Can someone please verify / check?

Comment: @Ralph unless the formula is entered with `.FormulaLocal` then formula must be in American English format, with English functions and `,` instead of `;` for the deliminator.